# PiCan 2 Data Logging on higher frequency problem

Tags: python, pi-3b+, arduino

I have a project that logs data from a vechicle's OBD 2 port (using PiCan2 on top of RPi3B) and combines that data with data from sensors connected to an external Arduino. The Arduino communicates with the RPi via USB serial. I have set the code to write the values to a .txt file, seperated by commas. Each line is a separate data frame. The code is set  to take a data sample every time the GPS (Neo 6M) is updated. The program works as expected at 1Hz which is the default Neo 6M update rate, BUT after setting the GPS to work at 5Hz for more accuracy on road events, I get periodical losses on data collecting. The first picture is from 1Hz and the second is from 5Hz. Notice the data gaps.[image: 1st Image]

[image: 2nd Image]

The python code is a modified version from [here](https://github.com/skpang/PiCAN-Python-examples). I used the obdii_logger.py and simple_coolant to create this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import can
import string
from threading import Thread

from datetime import datetime
ln=datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y___%H-%M-%S rduversion')
index=0
start_time=time.time()
led = 22
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(led,True)
INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE = 0x0F
ENGINE_RPM          = 0x0C
ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP = 0x05
VEHICLE_SPEED       = 0x0D
PID_REQUEST         = 0x7DF
PID_REPLY           = 0x7E8
file=open("rest9.txt","a")
os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")
time.sleep(0.1)
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000")
print('Ready')
try:
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan_native')
except OSError:
    print('Cannot find PiCAN board.')
    GPIO.output(led,False)
    exit()

  
def can_rx_task():
    while True:
        message = bus.recv()
        
        
        if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_RPM:
            c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)
            s=''
            for i in range(message.dlc ):
                s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])
            rpm = round(((message.data[3]*256) + message.data[4])/4)
            file.write(str(rpm)+",")
            print(str(rpm))
        
        if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == VEHICLE_SPEED:
            c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)
            s=''
            for i in range(message.dlc ):
                s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])
            speed = message.data[3]
            file.write(str(speed)+",")
            print(str(speed))
        
        #if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE:
            #c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)
            #s=''
            #for i in range(message.dlc ):
                #s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])
            #airtemperature = message.data[3] - 40
            #file.write(str(airtemperature)+",")
            #print(str(airtemperature))

t = Thread(target = can_rx_task)
t.start()

try:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        


    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()+"\n"
            file.write(datetime.today().strftime('%H-%M-%S,'))
            file.write(line)
            msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,VEHICLE_SPEED,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
            bus.send(msg)
            time.sleep(0.05)
            msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_RPM,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
            bus.send(msg)
            time.sleep(0.05)
            
            #msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],extended_id=False)
            #bus.send(msg)
            #time.sleep(0.05)
            #file.close()
            print(line)
            print(index)
            
            index+=1

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #Catch keyboard interrupt
    GPIO.output(led,False)
    end_time=time.time()
    elapsed_time=end_time-start_time
    print('Execution time: '+str(int(elapsed_time)))
    file.close()
    os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 down")
    print('\n\rKeyboard interrtupt')
```

Also here is the Arduino Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
const int x=A1;
const int y=A2;
const int z=A3;
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
TinyGPSPlus gps; 
SoftwareSerial ss(4,3);

const unsigned char UBLOX_INIT[] PROGMEM={
0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x08,0x06,0x00,0xC8,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0xDE,0x6A
};


  
  
void setup(void)
{
  ss.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);


  for(unsigned int i=0;i<sizeof(UBLOX_INIT);i++){
    ss.write(pgm_read_byte(UBLOX_INIT+i));
    }
  
}

void loop(){

  while(ss.available()>0){
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if(gps.location.isUpdated()){
  /* Get a new sensor event */
 
int sensorRD=analogRead(A0);
if(sensorRD<600){
Serial.print("2");
Serial.print(",");
}
else if(sensorRD>900){
  Serial.print("0");
  Serial.print(",");
  }
else if(sensorRD>600 && sensorRD<900){
Serial.print("1");
Serial.print(",");
}
 
  Serial.print(analogRead(x)); Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(analogRead(y)); Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(analogRead(z)); Serial.print(",");
  
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(","); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }
  }
  }
```

The data loss occurs ONLY when I send 3 or more different PID requests to the ECU. The program was working perfectly with 4 PIDs on 1Hz. How can I read more PIDs at 5hz without data loss? Am running out of Ram? buffer space? I have googled everything and cant seem to be able to fix the problem.

Comment: You are probably running out of CPU time; in the Python code, you are sleeping for 3 x 0.05 seconds, which doesn't leave much time for your code to do anything useful, if the data is arriving every 0.2 seconds. You need to re-structure the code to avoid this time-wasting.

Comment: This is exactly what happened! I lowered it to 0.01 secs and I was able to read more PIDs Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.i made a logger which reads serial data from rs232.

I am working on project.

This project save weight value when a button is pressed

Raspberry pi is connected with rs232 to get serial data

I have already made the code.

Reads serial data
Get float value from serial read(bec it is a string)
Put logic on that float value,if Flaot >= 7:
Save float value in sd card when button is pressed.
I used while loop in upper logic which will break the loop if float >= 6

It is saving the float value properly but as there are so many readings to be saved it sometimes doesnt save the float value in sd card.

Suppose out of 2200 bags i will miss to save 190 bags float value

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130067)